# docker push to local registry fails

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Registry container is running at port 5000.

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
accbeafa34fe   ibmcom/registry:2.6.2.5   "registry serve /etc…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   local-registry
```

```
sudo -E docker push localhost:5000/pgp-bench:latest
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/pgp-bench]
ca9a5caaa0d5: Pushed 
dd9235795971: Pushed 
4dfdebe31f24: Pushed 
98a59ff53764: Retrying in 1 second

-->on retrying
# docker push localhost:5000/pgp-bench:latest
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/pgp-bench]
Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

On curl, it keeps waiting

```
# curl http://localhost:5000
```

Logs of the registry container

```
time="2021-10-08T06:25:19.963905582Z" level=info msg="endpoint local-5003 disabled, skipping" environment=development go.version=go1.11.9 ins
tance.id=88f73ea0-77d6-425f-8259-0b3717c76b7a service=registry version=e38b0207                                                              
time="2021-10-08T06:25:19.963921607Z" level=info msg="endpoint local-8083 disabled, skipping" environment=development go.version=go1.11.9 ins
tance.id=88f73ea0-77d6-425f-8259-0b3717c76b7a service=registry version=e38b0207                                                              
time="2021-10-08T06:25:19.964454493Z" level=info msg="using redis blob descriptor cache" environment=development go.version=go1.11.9 instance
.id=88f73ea0-77d6-425f-8259-0b3717c76b7a service=registry version=e38b0207                                                                   
time="2021-10-08T06:25:19.964744256Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" environment=development go.version=go1.11.9 instance.id=88f73ea
0-77d6-425f-8259-0b3717c76b7a service=registry version=e38b0207  
time="2021-10-08T06:25:59.965390038Z" level=debug msg="filesystem.Stat(\"/\")" 
environment=development go.version=go1.11.9 instance.id=88f73e
a0-77d6-425f-8259-0b3717c76b7a service=registry trace.duration=35.698µs trace.file="/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/d
river/base/base.go" trace.func="github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/driver/base.(*Base).Stat" trace.id=8f6467ca-1438-45cc-9910-6c
ba6845ca83 trace.line=137 version=e38b0207
```

I have tried all the possible options mentioned in similar issues such as

1. [net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570423/net-http-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection-client-timeout-exceeded)
2. https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/196

but nothing seems to help resolve the issue. Any suggestions on how to approach a solution?

Comment: What happens if you `curl -4 http://localhost:5000/v2/`?

Comment: Can you share logs of your container accbeafa34fe while doing such requests?

Comment: @BMitch, on curl, there's no o/p and it just waits.

Comment: @TruongHua, I have added the logs to the question above since they couldn't be accommodated in the comment character limit.

Comment: I'd check if a firewall setting is blocking the request.

Comment: On retrial, I see the below message now,
`# curl -4 http://localhost:5000/v2/`
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`
`# curl -4 http://localhost:5000/v2/`
`{}`
First it says the connection is reset by peer and then I see an o/p of empty body. Then it again keeps waiting as before.

Comment: I checked from within the container if it is listening on port 5000  and it is.

Comment: And regarding firewall setting -- `# ufw status
Status: inactive`

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue.

I changed the tag name to be `127.0.0.1:5000` instead of `localhost` and it completed as expected when pushing.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, local registry was connected to the kind cluster.
`docker push` worked after I disconnected registry from the network:
`docker network disconnect "kind" "kind-registry"`