# Unable to push Docker images to local registry, client times out

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, networking, kind

I'm writing as I've encountered an issue that doesn't seem to get resolved, would value the community's help.

I'm trying to push an image to a local registry I deployed on port 5000.

When I use this command `docker push localhost:5000/explorecalifornia.com` to push the image to my local registry, I get the following message

```
Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I've confirmed the registry is on port 5000 by using GET on postman, and I get a valid, expected `{}` response (since there's no images currently on my local registry).

I've since tried to fix this by updating my `etc/hosts` file to comment out "::1 localhost" per advise of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570423/net-http-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection-client-timeout-exceeded). This is the contents of my `etc/hosts` file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
# ::1 localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I also updated my `etc/resolve.conf` file with the following nameservers per advise from this [post](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611#issuecomment-531764867).

```
nameserver 10.0.2.3
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

None of this worked. Did anyone also encounter this issue? Is there any recommendations to help fix this issue?

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/keshinpoint/Explore-California) if it helps! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I use a  work-around for this error and it is as below:

Firstly, tag the images using the localhost ip instead, ie

```
docker tag imagename 127.0.0.1:5000/imagename
```

and,

```
docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/imagename
```

I hope this works for you as well.

Comment: You can format the code that you have provided - two backticks at the start and two at the end for a little piece of code inserted in your text - four spaces at the front of the code line to create a code block - it makes it look nicer! It's definitely worth giving it a go.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same type of problem. Not able to push an image to a local-registry deployed on port 5000.

Run the following command:

```
docker network disconnect kind local-registry
```

This will allow you to successfully push the image. Then enable the docker network to the kind cluster with the following command:

```
docker network connect kind local-registry
```

Once you enable it then you can go ahead and apply the deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a HTTP proxy defined. Please try running these commands.

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I ran both of these commands and tried, but get this message `Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be sth changed with the kind image. I use the script from this page:
https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/

I am able to create a new kind cluster and registry. After that, I have no problem following the video lecture to push the explorecalifornia.com image to the local registry.