# Getting timeouts on `az acr login` in Windows though `az acr health-check` shows that ACR is healthy

Tags: azure, docker, docker-container, acr

Whenever I'm running `az acr login -n` i'm getting following message:

Error response from daemon: Get "https://acrau*****.azurecr.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Login failed.

In the same time when I call `az acr check-health -n acraues****` it says it can reach the ACR registry and challenge the token.

I suppose the issue is with connectivity however I'm having trouble to debug this.

What's the best way to debug this problem to find what's failing the command?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

> "https://acrau*****.azurecr.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) Login failed.

The above error states an issue with the destination's reachability. When using a virtual network, a firewall, or a proxy server to access an Azure container registry. you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570423/net-http-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection-client-timeout-exceeded) to verify.

If your accessing the container registry behind the network firewall with data endpoints make sure you have **Enable dedicated data endpoint**

Portal -> container registry -> networking -> enable dedicated data endpoint.

[image]

Now, you can use the same command to log in to the container registry for a workaround:

**Commands:**

```
az login 
az acr login --name  <acrName>
az account set --subscription "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
#Importing image to repository
az acr import --name <acrname> --source docker.io/library/httpd:latest --image httpd:latest -g <resource-grp-name>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Troubleshoot network issues with registry - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-troubleshoot-access#configure-client-firewall-access)